# Non-desired contoured font

Tags: fonts

Almost all apps in my tablet with Android 7.1 use beside "normal" fonts an hardly readable *contoured font:*

[image]
[image]

Is there some way to *substitute it with non-contoured font*?

Comment: Turn off the High Contrast text in the Settings>Display

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow, **yes**, thank you very much! (Setting>Accessibility>Display). Please rewrite is as an answer to allow me accept and vote up it.

Comment: posted an answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to Settings > Accessibility > Display and then turn off High Contrast Text

[image]